# Webclient always returns an empty Source Code

Tags: vb.net, webclient

I would like to get the source code of this page for exemple:

[My page URL](https://www.virustotal.com/fr/file/c65ce5ab02b69358d07b56434527d3292ea2cb12357047e6a396a5b27d9ef680/analysis/)

I used Webclient (DownloadString and DownloadFile) or HttpWebRequest. But, I always get return an empty string (Code source).

With firefox, Edge or other browser, I get the code source without problem.

How can I get the source code of the given exemple.

---

This a code of many codes that I used:

```
Using client = New WebClient()
    client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0")
    Dim MyURL As String = "https://www.virustotal.com/fr/file/c65ce5ab02b69358d07b56434527d3292ea2cb12357047e6a396a5b27d9ef680/analysis/"
    Dim Source_Code As String = client.DownloadString(MyURL)
    MsgBox(Source_Code)
    textbox1.text = Source_Code
End Using
```

---

NB 2: Webclient works fine with all other sites.

NB 1: I don't like to use Webbrowser or such control.

Comment: What code are you using to download this?

Comment: @It'sNotALie.
I edit the topic with an exemple code.

Comment: @Dot_NET Pro
I edit the topic with an exemple code.

Comment: Are you sure the links are correct? In a browser they return 404 - that's the error code for a missing page. I suspect you've wrapped your code with a try/catch block and discard any errors

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos
Thanks, I edited the link.
My codes does not retrun any errors or exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the target server is picky and requires the `Accept-Language` header to return any content. The following code returns the page's content:

```
var url="https://www.virustotal.com/fr/file/c65ce5ab02b69358d07b56434527d3292ea2cb12357047e6a396a5b27d9ef680/analysis/";
var client=new System.Net.WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("Accept-Language","en");
var content=client.DownloadString(url);
```

If the `Accept-Language` header is missing, no data is returned.

To find this, you can use a tool like Fiddler to capture the HTTP request and responses from your browser and application. By removing one by one the headers sent by the browser, you can find which header the server actually requires.